# How to reuse graphQl resolvers

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

My project based on Node, GraphQl (apollo), MongoDb.
I have basic entity Product:

```
type Product {
  id: ObjectId
  name: String
  bestPrice: Number
  annualSavings: Number
  ...
}
```

bestPrice and annualSavings are calculated in base on separate resolvers:

```
const bestPriceResolver = (product, args, context) => {
   return getBestPrice(context.dataStore)
}

const annualSavingsResolver = (product, args, context) => {
   const bestPrice = getBestPrice(context.dataStore);
   return getAnnualSavings = getAnnualSavings(bestPrice);
}

composeResolvers ({
  bestPrice: bestPriceResolver,
  annualSavings: annualSavingsResolver, 
})
```

Each resolver goes to database and fetch data for bestPrice. And with this approach I go to dadabase twice to fetch same data (bestPrice). Is it possible to do it once?

Comment: you can simply (over-)fetch it in `Product` resolver and access by `product.bestPrice`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using dataloader (https://github.com/graphql/dataloader). It's a generic utility which provides batching of requests (and also caching per request).
Throughout request you can collect all ids of some entity that you need, and then you can execute only one query with provided ids.

General idea is that you create new instance of loader for each request and store it in context. Then, instead of calling getBestPrice, you call loader's .load() or .prime() method, which basically collects all ids throughout request. Dataloader returns new function, which should be similar to getBestPrice, but instead of making one query per id, you'll need to provide an array of ids in query, and map responses according to order of ids provided. Dataloader will do the rest :)

Dataloader helps a lot with GraphQL optimizations, since GraphQL queries can often be very heavy.

YouTube provides tons of useful tutorials.